# What is the most efficent single-source shorthest path algorithm in unweighted directed grid graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

As regards the topic.
Here is an example of such a graph:
[image: unweighted directed grid graph]

Comment: You want something better than a BFS?

Comment: i guess @ChristopherBoo said the best for this thing is bfs:)